# How can I specify time limit to a chrome push notification

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, web-push, chrome-gcm

I used Service Worker to send Push Notifications to chrome browser.

I used below code to receive notification from server

```
 var url = "path/to/your/json/file/json-data.php?param="+Math.random();
 self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {    
  event.waitUntil(  
    fetch(url).then(function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        // Either show a message to the user explaining the error  
        // or enter a generic message and handle the
        // onnotificationclick event to direct the user to a web page  
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + response.status);  
        throw new Error();  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      return response.json().then(function(data) {  
        if (data.error || !data.notification) {  
          console.log('The API returned an error.', data.error);  
          throw new Error();  
        }  
        var title = data.notification.title;  
        var message = data.notification.message;  
        var icon = data.notification.icon;  

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
          data: {
            url: data.notification.url
          }  
        });  
      });  
    }).catch(function(err) {  
      console.log('Unable to retrieve data', err);

      var title = 'An error occurred';
      var message = 'We were unable to get the information for this push message';  
      var icon = 'img/design19.jpg';  
      var notificationTag = 'notification-error';  
      return self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
          body: message,  
          icon: icon,  
          tag: notificationTag  
        });  
    })  
  );  
});

// The user has clicked on the notification ...
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {  
  console.log(event.notification.data.url);
  // Android doesn't close the notification when you click on it  
  // See: http://crbug.com/463146  
  event.notification.close();

  // This looks to see if the current is already open and  
  // focuses if it is  
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({  
      type: "window"  
    })
    .then(function(clientList) {  
      for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {  
        var client = clientList[i];  
        if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)  
          return client.focus();  
      }  
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        return clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url);  
      }
    })
  );
});
```

Notification is displaying but it is closing after a few seconds. I don't need to close the notification. The user explicitly closes the notification. Tell me the code to stop closing the notification. Once the notification is displayed it is not closing forever. User explicitly close the notification

Answer (score 2):

*return self.registration.showNotification(title, {

          body: message,

          icon: icon,

          tag: notificationTag

        });*

You can add requireInteraction: true to the notification porperties dictionary. This will make it stay on screen. Note that this is not guaranteed to work in all platforms but today at least it works ok in chrome desktop.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of notifications to show on the screen. At present I have many notifications and I need to close one by one

Comment: This should probably its own question.